# Manipulating sql database data

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a column called "enc_cmd_num" which is the order number.

Another one is called "enc_paye" which displays 1 (if the order is paid), 0 (if the order is not paid)

All this comes from a table called "encaissement".

My problem is as follows:

I can display the data that come from a Microsoft database in which I use OBDC.

I would like to be able to display in a screen when the order number (which comes from the table "enc_cmd_num") is paid, (display that it is put in preparation), but if this one is not paid, that it is in "waiting for payment".

Thanks again for your precious help.

I tried to search the internet but no one is concrete in what they say....

Comment: mysql <> mssql also research sql case

Comment: So I have to use "case" to be able to retrieve the data and set a condition?

Comment: For some tips on how you could improve your question see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) and how to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)